# how to visualize inflation layer in RViz?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

to make some observation, I want to visualize inflation layer in RViz. how can I do that ?
like here:
[inflation in rviz](https://www.google.de/search?q=ros+inflation+radius&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHvdPXh6XZAhXqAsAKHVxJBFIQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=1007#imgrc=SVy1jX-sJSmnVM:)

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282673/how-to-visualize-inflation-layer-in-rviz-?/) by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2018-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris_sunny](https://answers.ros.org/users/32569/chris_sunny/) on 2018-02-14**:
http://learn.turtlebot.com/

Towards the end of this tutorial , you would have learned about making a SLAM enabled robot using Gmapping . In that you will encounter inflation on Rviz .

**Comment by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on 2018-02-14**:
not clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming that you are working with move_base... the inflation layer can be visualized in rviz as a costmap. Just add a map topic to rviz and select it to hear the costmap topic (i.e. /move_base/local_costmap/costmap). Then select "Color Scheme" -> costmap, the result will be the same as the picture you have pointed out in your comment.

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2018-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on 2018-03-06**:
thanks I have solved also in that way

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-05-11**:
@Developer if this answered your question then please click the checkmark to mark the answer as correct.